# Mapping not working?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-binding

I have a weird situtation, i have 1 master class called User, this is an abstract class. It cointains 3 child classes (Student, Promotor and BPC) who always inherit from User.

I am using the TPH (Table per Hierarchy) structure to map this to the database, the Discriminator field is just the name of the class.

a Student has a relationship with Promotor. It can contain 0 or 1 promotor. With the initializer i make sure that a Student has the corresponding promotor. (it shows correctly in my database after launch)

When i try to use the modelbinder to get the Student from the logged in user it returns the correct student but it says it doesnt contain a promotor.

**Class User:**

```
public abstract class User
{
    //TPH is default
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String Username { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }

    public String Salt { get; set;}
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
    public String LastIp { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public String PlainPassword { get; set; }

}
```

**Class Student**

```
public class Student : User
{
    public virtual Promotor Promotor { get; set; }
    public virtual CoPromotor CoPromotor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Suggestion> Suggestions { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {
        Suggestions = new Collection<Suggestion>();
    }
}
```

**Class Promotor**

```
public class Promotor : User
{
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public List<User> users;
    private String message;

    public Promotor()
    {
        Students = new Collection<Student>();
        users = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

**User model binder**

```
public class UserModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            IUserRepository repos =
                (IUserRepository) DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof (IUserRepository));
            return repos.FindByUsername(controllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Action in the controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel model, User user, string btnSaveSend)
{
     var student = (Student) user; //here the attribute Promotor is NULL
}
```

**User mapper:**

```
public class UserMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMapper()
    {
        ToTable("user");  

        // Primary key
        HasKey(u => u.Id);

        // Properties
        Property(u => u.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(u => u.FirstName).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.LastName).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.Email).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.Salt).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.Username).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.Password).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.LastLogin);
        Property(u => u.LastIp);
        Property(u => u.CreationDate).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.LastPasswordChangedDate).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

**Student Mapper**

```
public class StudentMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public StudentMapper()
    {
        HasMany(s => s.Suggestions).WithRequired(s => s.Student);
        HasRequired(s => s.Promotor).WithMany(s => s.Students);
    }
 }
```

UserRepository:

```
public User FindByUsername(string name)
 {
     return users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username.ToLower() == name.ToLower());
 }
```

Comment: What happens in `repos.FindByUsername`?

Comment: It finds the user by its username (i updated the original post)

Comment: You should use `Include`: `users.Include(u => u.Promotor).FirstOrDefault...`

Comment: The problem is that this is from type User, which is the abstract class, only Student (inherits from User) has the property Promotor

Comment: as you can see i have set my Promotor property to virtual so it should pull the Promotor in which it doesnt.

Comment: what about the emitted SQL ? Never get good results with embeding ToLower in the query. Sounds like the selection was made out of the dbcontext context.

Comment: The emitted SQL is correct